# Can't remove margin with guidline

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I've simple view, fragment container button on the bottom side.
I've used guidline horizontal and now I've margin on the top and on the bottom of buttons.
I don't see this margins in the code, so why I've this margins and how to remove it ?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:name="com.package.list.ListFragment"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </fragment>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="List"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You will use a command inside Android Studio called `go to declaration` which is `cmd+B` on a Mac or `ctrl+B` on Windows. I will just use `ctrl+B` for simplicity.

### Answer

I think it's because of the default style that is applied to buttons. If you search for it in Android Studio you can actually see that `Button` style contains a background like this:

```xml
<item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape</item>
```

And then when you `ctrl+B` this file you will see something called `insetTop` and `insetBottom`

```xml
<inset 
    android:insetTop="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material"
    android:insetBottom="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material">
```

Again, `ctrl+B` inside and you finally see that they are both equal to **6dp**. So in you main activity, all you need to do, is set the `insetTop` and `insetBottom` to `0dp` like this:

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/list_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
    android:text="List"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2" />
```

Comment: where you have found "<item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_btn_default_mtrl_shape</item>" ?

Comment: I found it inside `Widget.AppCompat.Button` style. You can try command `Find in Path` and search for this name.